gitlab SSO by auth2。 Could not authenticate you from OAuth2Generic because "Access token=at-7-rntqvebyapaudq3y3s1aazfqnae4krmw&expires in=28800"
Could not authenticate you from OAuth2Generic because "Access token=at-7-rntqvebyapaudq3y3s1aazfqnae4krmw&expires in=28800".
`gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
{
'name' => 'oauth2_generic',
'label': 'SSO',
'app_id' => '20180901',
'app_secret' => '123456',
'args' => {
client_options: {
'site' => 'http://192.168.3.96:30002',
"authorize_url" => '/cas/oauth2.0/authorize',
"token_url" => '/cas/oauth2.0/accessToken',
"user_info_url" => '/cas/oauth2.0/profile'
},
user_response_structure: {
root_path: ['attributes'],
id_path: ['email'],
attributes: {email: 'email', username:'username'}
},
        strategy_class: "OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2Generic"
    }
}`

]
